# This is the explanation on recursion tracing, and I can't understand some logic in it. What is the logic?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, logic, big-o

Consider:

[image]

The function written in this picture is for explaining recursion. It says that the function takes T(n) time to run, but it contains a recursive call and then it takes T(n-1) time to run.

But we know that function takes T(n) time and the same function call is taken. Then it should again take T(n) time, because the function is doing the same thing as before. Am I wrong in understanding the concept or is the concept wrongly explained in the code?

Comment: The first time you call `Test(n)` with `n>0`, it calls `printf()`. That completes the first step, so naturally there are `n-1` steps left. This is done by the call to `Test(n-1)`.

In general, a good way to understand recursive functions is to start with `n=0` and manually step through the function and see what happens. Then do `n=1`, `n=2`, etc. until you build up your intuition for what is happening.

Comment: Actually here the total function execution will take T(n) time, only one iteration of the function call with take a constant time or say T(1). And as the function will call itself n times progressively so the total time will be T(n).

Comment: @Tamim But note that `printf("%d", n)` actually takes O(log n) time, because there are log10(n) digits to print. :-)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Related: *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)* and *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is this

```
void Test(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("%d",n);        // 1
        Test(n-1);             // T(n-1)
    }
}
// T(n) = T(n-1) + 1
```

By definition `T(n)` is the time taken by `Test(n)`. Also `T(n-1)` is just a label for "time taken to call `Test(n-1)`".

As the function only calls `printf` which is constant complexity, it is counted as 1 instruction, and calls `Test(n-1)`, its total runtime is `T(n) = T(n-1) + 1`.

> But we know that function takes T(n) time and same function call is taken then it should again take T(n) time because function is doing same thing as before.

No, `T(n-1)` is not the same as `T(n)` because `Test(n)` is not doing the same as `Test(n-1)`. `Test(n)` is doing the same as `Test(n-1)` plus calling `printf` once.